# numpyの行列で、ある特定の行を全て０にするにはどうしたらよいですか？

Tags: numpy

numpyの処理について質問です。たとえば以下に示す A のような行列があるとき、
最終行を全て `0` とした 行列 B を得るにはどうしたら良いでしょうか？
ご教示よろしくお願いします。

```
A=[
  [0,1,2],
  [3,4,5],
  [6,7,8]
]
```

```
B =[
  [0,1,2],
  [3,4,5],
  [0,0,0]
]
```

Comment: 公式ドキュメント（https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.indexing.html）は確認されましたか？

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```py
import numpy as np

A = np.array([[0, 1, 2], [3, 4, 5], [6, 7, 8]])
B = np.copy(A)
B[-1] = 0

# Python 3.8 以降であれば := (walrus operator)を使って以下の様にも書けます
# (B := np.copy(A))[-1] = 0

print(f'B:\n{B}')
print(f'A:\n{A}')

# 実行結果
B:
[[0 1 2]
 [3 4 5]
 [0 0 0]]
A:
[[0 1 2]
 [3 4 5]
 [6 7 8]]
```

`B = np.copy(A)` としていますが、`B = A` としてしまうと shallow copy になってしまいます。

```py
A = np.array([[0, 1, 2], [3, 4, 5], [6, 7, 8]])
B = A
B[-1] = 0

print(f'B:\n{B}')
print(f'A:\n{A}')

# 実行結果
B:
[[0 1 2]
 [3 4 5]
 [0 0 0]]
A:
[[0 1 2]
 [3 4 5]
 [0 0 0]]
```

Comment: metropolis様、どうもありがとうございました。ご教示いただいた通り実施したところ、こちらが期待する結果となりました。一度 np.copy()でコピーする必要があるのですね。非常に助かりました。